# Select All not working in a WordPress search filter

Tags: php, filters, taxonomy, search

I am trying to create a Search Filter within WordPress to filter through all the custom taxonomies within a Custom Post Type.

I have created a function that generates the dropdown so I can output each option value as a slug for my filter which is working already. My only issue is that the "Select All" option is not working.

The results come back with nothing found when Selecting All. The filter can be [here](http://adoptapet.ie/pets/farms).

The code I have used to create the function is:

```
function adopt_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy, $orderby = 'date', $order = 'DESC', $limit = '-1', $name, $show_option_all = null, $show_option_none = null ) {
$args = array(
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'number' => $limit,

);
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
$name = ( $name ) ? $name : $taxonomy;
if ( $terms ) {
    printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', esc_attr( $name ) );
    if ( $show_option_all ) {
        printf( '<option value="0">%s</option>', esc_html( $show_option_all ) );
    }
    if ( $show_option_none ) {
        printf( '<option value="-1">%s</option>', esc_html( $show_option_none ) );
    }
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr( $term->slug ), esc_html( $term->name ) );
    }
    print( '</select>' );
}
}
```

and this is where the results are being pulled to...

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET["farm-type"]) && empty($_GET["location-farms"])){

        $farm_type = $_GET["farm-type"];

        $myquery1['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'farm-type',
                'terms' => array($farm_type),
                'field' => 'slug',

            ),
        );
        query_posts($myquery1);

        }
        ?>

        <?php
        if (isset($_GET["farm-type"]) && isset($_GET["location-farms"])){

        $farm_type = $_GET["farm-type"];
        $farm_location = $_GET["location-farms"];

        $myquery2['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'farm-type',
                'terms' => array($farm_type),
                'field' => 'slug',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'location-farms',
                'terms' => array($farm_location),
                'field' => 'slug',
            ),
        );
        query_posts($myquery2);

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What processes the search?

Comment: Added extra code to show where the search is being pulled to @s_ha_dum

Comment: I would strongly advise against the use of `query_posts`, there is no reason this couldn't use a `WP_Query` object or the `pre_get_posts` filter to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. Your form `action` is incorrect: `<form method="get"
   action="http://www.adoptapet.ie/archive-farm/">`. The page is `<form
   method="get" action="http://www.adoptapet.ie/archive-farms/">`
2. You should reorder your argument list for
   `adopt_custom_taxonomy_dropdown()`. As written, most of your
   arguments have default values and can be omitted when the function
   is called, except that as written argument five doesn't have a
   default so you can't in practice omit two, three, and four. Move
   `$name` to the front-- much better usability.

   ```
   adopt_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy, $name, $orderby = 'date', $order = 'DESC', $limit = '-1', $show_option_all = null, $show_option_none = null )
   ```
3. [Don't use `query_posts()`, ever. It clobbers the main query and can
   cause numerous problems.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21376%20query_posts)
4. While I have not edited the code into the suggestions below, you
   should not ever use user supplied data like `$_GET` without
   [sanitizing it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). `$_GET` and `$_POST` ***are not safe***.

I think your problem is mostly a logic issue. This...

```
isset($_GET["farm-type"]) && isset($_GET["location-farms"])
```

.... is always going to be true. `$_GET["farm-type"]` and `$_GET["location-farms"]` are always going to be *set* when your form submits, even if they are empty. You should be using `!empty()` instead.

And you can clean up this code *a lot*:

```
if (!empty($_GET["farm-type"])){
  $farm_type = $_GET["farm-type"];
  $myquery['tax_query'][] = 
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'farm-type',
      'terms' => array($farm_type),
      'field' => 'slug',
    );
}

if (!empty($_GET["location-farms"])){
  $farm_location = $_GET["location-farms"];
  $myquery['tax_query'][] = 
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'location-farms',
      'terms' => array($farm_location),
      'field' => 'slug',
    );
}

if (!empty($myquery)) {
  $q = new WP_Query($myquery); // instead of wp_query()
  var_dump($q);
}
```

And you probably want an `AND` relationship between your two components.

```
if (!empty($myquery)) {
  if (1 < count($myquery['tax_query'])) {
    $myquery['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
  }
  $q = new WP_Query($myquery);
  var_dump($q->request); // debug
}
```

Now, if you pass an empty string for your "Select All" option instead of a number, I believe you should get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum for your very very detailed answer, I have a lot to learn!  I fixed point 1.  I amended point 2 but it seemed to try search by the date instead of the taxonomy so I swapped it back for now.  I have also added the code you then suggested however when I search now for All, no results come back and when I try some of the options, I get a lot of code displaying on the results page!  I also removed the number from the value in this line `printf( '<option value="">%s</option>', esc_html( $show_option_all ) )` What have I done wrong on this? :) http://adoptapet.ie/pets/farms.